# Client openvpn on debian: connection error ( virtual private server )

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn

I tested this account VPN on Windows and it connects well , I tried openvpn on Debian tested on a virtual private server and I get the error below. It is I who has masked the IP VPN, below is a copy/paste of the error.

```
root@eljis:~/Desktop/freedom# openvpn free.conf
Thu Nov 24 16:00:00 2011 OpenVPN 2.1.3 i486-pc-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [PF_INET6] [eurephia] built on Oct 21 2010
Enter Auth Username:fip_115e8vc19L
Enter Auth Password:
Thu Nov 24 16:01:03 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Thu Nov 24 16:01:03 2011 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Thu Nov 24 16:01:03 2011 LZO compression initialized
Thu Nov 24 16:01:03 2011 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]94                                  .23.146.141:443 [nonblock]
Thu Nov 24 16:01:04 2011 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]94.23.XXX.XXX:443
Thu Nov 24 16:01:04 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Thu Nov 24 16:01:04 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]94.23.XXX.XXX:443
Thu Nov 24 16:01:04 2011 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Nov 24 16:01:05 2011 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]94.23.XXX.XXX:443
Thu Nov 24 16:01:07 2011 Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Thu Nov 24 16:01:07 2011 Note: Attempting fallback to kernel 2.2 TUN/TAP interface
Thu Nov 24 16:01:07 2011 Cannot allocate TUN/TAP dev dynamically
Thu Nov 24 16:01:07 2011 Exiting
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is partially true. I have OpenVZ based VPS any my hosting company has "enable TUN/TAP" in their web admin page, after I enabled it openvpn started without any errors.

I'm not affiliated with them in any way, just a client, but do check them out:
http://www.prometeus.net/

Here are detailed instructions how you can make OpenVPN work in OpenVZ virtual instance (vps):
https://blog.ipredator.se/howto/getting-openvpn-to-work-with-openvz.html

Answer (score 0):

Many VPS providers don't provide the required kernel modules to use TUN/TAP devices. That is because all VPS on one host are using a shared kernel of the host system. OpenVZ, Virtuoso, and Linux vServer based host systems are doing this. There are other virtualisation technologies that are not using a shared kernel (XEN, KVM, VMWare). But those vServers are mostly more expensive (because of they generate more overhead).

It's impossible to run openvpn client/server on such a VPS.